# ignore lines with particular words in vimdiff output

Tags: vim, vimdiff

I have 2 large files to take vimdiff. In vimdiff output I want to ignore lines showing diff but  have a particular word.

e.g. in my case I want to ignore diff of all lines with prefix `WARNING:`  in my files.

Thanks,

Answer (score 8):

In order to achieve this, you could add the following to your .vimrc (a simple-minded modification from the example found by running `:h diffexpr` within vim):

```
set diffexpr=MyDiff()
function! MyDiff()
    let opt = ""
    if exists("g:diffignore") && g:diffignore != ""
        let opt = "-I " . g:diffignore . " "
    endif
    if &diffopt =~ "icase"
        let opt = opt . "-i "
    endif
    if &diffopt =~ "iwhite"
        let opt = opt . "-b "
    endif
    silent execute "!diff -a --binary " . opt . v:fname_in . " " .
        \ v:fname_new . " > " . v:fname_out
endfunction
```

It's noteworthy that the functionality provided by the `-I` (or `--ignore-matching-lines=`) switch for `diff` will ONLY ignore any changed lines where the line in BOTH (or all) files matches this expression.

See `man diff` for more details on the `--ignore-matching-lines=RE` switch and `:h diffexpr` within vim for more details on this.

EDIT: Added the optional variable `g:diffignore` to control what pattern to use. Also used `function!` to force replacement on definition.

Comment: I was hoping somebody else had this idea. Thanks for saving me needing to hack my .vimrc myself. I share it sometimes, so I've given you due credit. ;-)

Comment: To help a relative VIM novice, how to I set `g:diffignore`? What's the `g` prefix?

Comment: Ok, so you can set it with `:let g:diffignore='"your regex"'` (quotes stop it from getting broken on whitespace when the command line is built, one set eaten by vim, the other for the command line). You also need to do `:diffupdate` for it to come into effect.

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work with `:let g:diffignore='"^\s*\d\+:"'`? I'm trying to use it to ignore the hardcoded line numbers in FANUC TP programs. You can see an example program at https://www.onerobotics.com/posts/2014/tp-syntax-highlighting-with-pygments

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you filter the files before invoking vimdiff?

```
grep -v "^WARNING" file1 > file1_w; 
grep -v "^WARNING" file2 > file2_w; 
vimdiff file1_w file2_w
```

If you're using [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) or [zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Process-Substitution), you can do it with a single command:

```
vimdiff <(grep -v "^WARNING" file1) <(grep -v "^WARNING" file2)
```

Comment: This doesn't allow direct editing. General the purpose would be to edit file2 directly in place, except for the ignored lines.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked for a solution to this for a long time and I found the [EnhancedDiff plugin](https://github.com/chrisbra/vim-diff-enhanced) to be the easiest solution which makes your diffs slightly more intelligent to begin with :)

#### 1. Installation (https://github.com/chrisbra/vim-diff-enhanced#installation)

Use the plugin manager of your choice:

- [Pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen)

  - `git clone https://github.com/chrisbra/vim-diff-enhanced.git ~/.vim/bundle/vim-enhanced-diff`
  - `:Helptags` (only needed once after the installation to install the documentation)
- [NeoBundle](https://github.com/Shougo/neobundle.vim)

  - `NeoBundle 'chrisbra/vim-diff-enhanced'`
- [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle)

  - `Plugin 'chrisbra/vim-diff-enhanced'`
- [Vim-Plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug)

  - `Plug 'chrisbra/vim-diff-enhanced'`

#### 2. Diff as usual

Using `vimdiff`, `nvim -d` or `diffthis` for example

#### 3. Set the filter

```
:EnhancedDiffIgnorePat ^WARNING:.*
```

#### 4. Re-diff

```
:diffupdate
```

Comment: Nice, but as stated on the plugin's instructions page, this plugin is not required anymore:

`Starting with Vim 8.1.0360 Vim now comes bundled with the xdiff library and is able to handle diff internally without falling back to calling diff as external tool.

This means, one can now simply set diffopt:

if has("patch-8.1.0360")
    set diffopt+=internal,algorithm:patience
endif
and Vim will use the patience diff algorithm when creating a diff.`

So in essence, starting with that Vim version, you don't need to use this plugin anymore.

Comment: A quick google doesn't show me any alternative for the `:EnhancedDiffIgnorePat` though. Do you have any suggestions for that @HansDeragon?

Comment: Ugh... I was mixed up...  I will delete my comment.  Sad though that development of the plugin stopped....

Comment: No need for that. It's still useful information :)